# Removing all of the stop words in each tweet

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I want to remove all of the stop words in each tweet, but i'a, getting this error below.
I try finding solutions to figure it out, however i didn't find any.

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
print(stop_words)
nltk.download('punkt')
for all_words in words_in_tweet:
for a word in all_words:
```

```
#this is the error

File "<ipython-input-59-ade5bcf99259>", line 3
    for a word in all_words:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You just need to write `for word in all_words:` instead of `for a word...`

Answer (score 1):

[As jdaz said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866092/removing-all-of-the-stop-words-in-each-tweet/62866193#comment111170431_62866092), the `invalid syntax` error can be fixed by changing

```py
for a word in all_words:
    ...
```

to

```py
for word in all_words:
    ...
```

Comment: Trying that  i'am getting this error    ```File "<ipython-input-60-1de91e4ec2bb>", line 3
    for  word in all_words:
                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing```

Comment: I've just solved the problem, it's ok now, thank you guys.

Comment: If my answer helped, please could you accept it? Cheers.